# Retrieving two biggest ratings on Search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my new question:

On a search results page we have 12 products shown. 
All products with ratings above 3.7 have Rating Stars image and its value inside a span as a string:

```
<div class="searchResult">
<img src="#"/>
<span class="ratings">4.2</span>out of 5
</div>
```

There isn't any order to the way the prods are presented.

What I need is to get all products with Ratings greater than 4.5 and apply to the first and second big ones a background-color style.

How can that be done?
I managed a way to find the first two prods that have Ratings gt 4.5, but not the big ones.

E.g.: 5 prods have Ratings gt 4.5: 
4.6 , 
4.5 , 
5.0 , 
4.7 ,
4.9
In this case I need to apply via CSS the background-color only to those who have 5.0 and 4.9, not the first and second.

Well, here's the tricky part: **I can only use Javascript and jQuery** to solve this. The CSS part is ok, no problem.

I hope I made sense... Any question just ask me and I'll get to you asap. :)

Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) then [sort](http://api.jquery.com/sort):

```
$(".searchResult").filter(function() { //Filter down to results greater than 4.5

    return parseFloat($(this).find(".ratings").text()) > 4.5;

}).sort(function (a, b){ //Sort the remaining search results

    return parseFloat($(b).find(".ratings").text()) - parseFloat($(a).find(".ratings").text())  ;

}).filter(":lt(2)").css("background-color","red");  //Set the style of the first two elements
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVAe4/)

Comment: All answers did the trick perfectly!!
Thanks a lot guys!! You rawk!

Answer (score 2):

You need to first extract the matching divs as an array, and then sort that array. Both can be done in a single step using filter and sort functions:

```
var sortedarr = $('div.searchResult')
    .filter(function() { // only the high ratings
        return (+$(this).find('span.ratings').text() > 4.5);
    })
    .get() // convert to an array of DOM elements
    .sort(function(a, b) { // now sort from highest to lowest
        return ($(b).find('span.ratings').text() - $(a).find('span.ratings').text());
    });
$highest = $(sortedarr[0]);   // a jQuery object
$runnerup = $(sortedarr[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mgdGY/

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different method, don't know if it's better or likely worse :

```
var myarray= new Array();

$('.ratings').each(function() {
     myarray.push($(this).text());
});

function sortarray(a, b) {
     return (b - a);
}

myarray.sort(sortarray);

if (myarray[0] >= 4.5) {
     $('.ratings:contains('+myarray[0]+'):first').addClass('red');
}
if (myarray[1] >= 4.5) {
     $('.ratings:contains('+myarray[1]+'):not(.red):first').addClass('red');
}
```

With red as your background-color Class.

Likely worse, because it use :contains, which must be quite demanding.

Comment: Yep, more demanding but works too. Performance-wise had to choose the other way, through Filter and Sort. 
Thanks a lot, man! :)

Comment: Yes, Dennis's answer is better. I did not deleted mine because it uses :contains, which is not so well-known, so maybe it'll help someone someday. Good luck for your project !

Comment: Yes, please leave your answer here. It is useful! Thanks!  :)